# Can't find persistence unit and reverse engineering tools

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x, persistence.xml

I'm currently creating my entities and DAO with Hibernate Tools and reverse engineering. My config is Eclipse Indigo, JBoss AS7, Hibernate Tools 3.4 and Hibernate 4. The problem is when I try to deploy my .jar to JBoss AS7 I get this :

http://pastebin.com/1hvHBM7z

And more precisely :

> Can't find a persistence unit named null in deployment
>   "businessLayer.jar"

Now, I searched about this issue and it suggests I should have a persistence.xml file under META-INF. The thing is, the generation didn't do anything regarding this file (it even disabled its generation when I checked annotations and not JPA during the console config) and when I look at the samples, I'm unsure what to specify... 
Another question : from what I understand, this file is necessary for the EntityManager, but why would I need this if all the required informations is already in my hibernate.cfg.xml (because I mean, the two files look kinda similar...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it seems you need to have the persistence xml, which get rid of the issue above. Then you're likely to have a new exception : JDBC Driver not found etc. The problem came from JBoss 7 and Postgre9 for me. More information [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/168958) (last post).