# Why is persistence unit named null when persistence.xml exists

Tags: java, wildfly, entitymanager

I am using Wildfly 8.1 together with a EJB Project (EJB 3.2) containing entities. When trying to inject the Entity Manager into one of my Beans i get the following:

```
JBAS011440: Can't find a persistence unit named null in deployment \"EntitiesProject.jar\""},
"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"EntitiesProject.jar\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"EntitiesProject.jar\".beanmanager]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO.HandleDelegate is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO.ORB is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EntitiesProject.EntitiesProject.MitarbeiterDAO]"
]
```

This is my SessionBean where I try to inject the EntityManager:

```
@Stateless
public class MitarbeiterDAO implements MitarbeiterDAORemote {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public int writeMitarbeiterToDB(Mitarbeiter m)
    {
        em.persist(m);
        return m.getId();
    }
}
```

I have specified the following `persistence.xml` file which I put to "project-name"/ejbModule/META-INF.

```
<persistence-unit name="mitarbeiter">
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
   <properties>
      <property-name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
   </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**Similar questions and their solutions**

- [Can't find persistence unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512555/cant-find-persistence-unit-and-reverse-engineering-tools) suggests to include a persistence.xml
- [Injecting entityManager in Wildfly / Jboss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549026/injecting-entitymanager-in-jboss-wildfly) points out that there might be another directory where my persistence.xml belongs to. I tried that directory but still got the same error message.
- [Cannot find persistence unit from persistence.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435124/persistence-object-cannot-find-persistence-unit-from-persistence-xml) While this is not exactly the same question the solution was to add a `<provider>` to persistence.xml, but this also did not work for me

**Update (see comments):**
 - I have tried to use `@EntityManager(unitName="mitarbeiter")` instead
   of just `@EntityManager`
 - The Session Bean shown above is the only place where I try to inject
   `EntityManager`

**Update 2 (see comments of answer):**

- `persistence.xml` is in the directory `Project/ejbModule/META-INF/`
- This directory is included in the Build Path
- Somehow it's not getting deployed while other files in the same directory are (to `jar/META-INF/`). If I copy&paste it manually, it works. Why is that?

Any help and hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `unitName` optional property on your `@PersistenceContext` annotation?

Comment: yes I have tried using `@PersistenceContext(unitName="mitarbeiter")` instead of just `@PersistenceContext`.

Comment: OK, just checking.  It's not supposed to be needed unless there's more than one persistence unit.

Comment: The `persistence.xml` needs to be in the directory `META-INF` inside your JAR file. Is that the case?

Comment: As I just discovered it is not, but it should be. It is the only file in that directory that doesn't get deployed to `jar/META-INF`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of possible issues:

- Incorrect location of the `persistence.xml` file. Please place it inside `META-INF/` directory at the root of the archive. If you use maven it would be `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`.
- Invalid `persistence.xml` file: you have `persistence-unit` tag closed in line `<persistence-unit name="mitarbeiter"/>` (please notice `/` at the end)
- `<property-name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>` is invalid. I suppose you wanted: `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />`
- also provider you are using is deprecated.

In general, the correct `persistence.xml` content for JPA 2.1 in your case should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="mitarbeiter">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot! I just did not see things like this anymore after searching for a solution for hours! It got me closer to a solution: `persistence.xml` is in the right directory as far as I know: `Projektname/ejbModule/META-INF` but it's not getting geployed while anything else in this directory is. If I copy&paste it manually it works. What could that be?

Comment: @Jbartmann probably the directory is not added as source location in your build classpath

Comment: What I'm doing is: Rightclick Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Java Build Path -> Source. There is an item `Project/ejbModule` with `Included: All`. I changed it to `Included: {selected all Folders, including META-INF}`. Still does not deploy my persistence.xml. Is that what you were talking of? I can still get it running only by copy&paste manually. As soon as I do rightclick on server -> clean it gets deleted.

Comment: @Jbartmann I can see that you are using solely Eclipse. So please configure your `Deployment Assembly` (project -> Right click -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly). And add for example `META-INF` dir under `/META-INF` deploy path. But please keep in mind that when using Gradle or Maven you would be more portable/ IDE-independent.

Comment: @Jbartmann you may consider accepting answer if it answered your original question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have been chasing this problem for weeks. I'm using Wildfly 20, AdoptOpenJDK 14, Maven and MySql on MassiveGrid, a hosted server environment. What finally worked for me was a post I found on JBoss, which solved my problem. My test environment is Windows 10, which worked fine without the fix. The solution turned out to be adding a folder under Web Pages/META-INF named services and putting a file named java.sql.Driver with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  ~ JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
  ~ Copyright 2010, Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
  ~ as indicated by the @author tags. See the copyright.txt file in the
  ~ distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
  ~
  ~ This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
  ~ under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
  ~ published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
  ~ the License, or (at your option) any later version.
  ~
  ~ This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
  ~ Lesser General Public License for more details.
  ~
  ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  ~ License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
  ~ Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
  ~ 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
  -->

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```